# Use of undeclared type "xxx"エラーの解決に関して

Tags: swift

DatailViewControllerをsubclassにAVPlayerViewControllerを指定して、iOS Source > Cocoa Touch Classから作成しました。

その段階で「Use of undeclared type "AVPlayerViewController"/宣言されていない型を使うな!!」というエラーが生じました。

何かしら手助け頂ければ幸いです。

現在行っている解決策

1,Build PhasesからCompile SourcesでDetailViewController.swiftをaddすれば良いとググるとあったのですが、もう既にaddされている状態でした。

2,Taget Membershipにチェックを入れろとあったのですが、それも既にチェックされていました。

3,Cleanコマンド?を行う もしくはDerived Dataを消す 実行済み

4,新しいUIkitをimportする。これはやり方がわかりません。

Comment: プロジェクトの設定＞Generalで、「Linked Frameworks and Libraries」で、`AVKit`をリンクしていますか？

Comment: しておりませんでした。ご指摘ありがとうございます。
ご指摘頂いた点は、AVkit.frmeworks => addでよいのでしょうか。
AVFoundtaion.frameworkもaddするのでしょうか？

Comment: AVPlayerViewControllerをインポートするdetailViewController(今回使用するコントローラー名)がUse of undeclared type "detailViewController"となるなるため、仕様上使ってはいけ無いのかもしれません。

Comment: AVPlayerViewControllerをインポートするdetailViewController(今回使用するコントローラー名)がUse of undeclared type "detailViewController"となるなるため、仕様上使ってはいけ無いのかもしれません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

今どきのプロジェクトではAutoLinkが働くのでリンカの設定はおそらく関係ないですね。単純に`import`文がないのではないかと思いますが、`import AVKit`は書いてますか？

普通にプロジェクトを作成して、下記のように書けばビルドエラーにはならないと思います。下記と比べてみてください。

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class ViewController: AVPlayerViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: 下記のコードを記述しておりました。

上記のコードに書き換えたところ、エラーが生じなくなりました。
今回はありがとうございます。


```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class DetailViewController: AVPlayerViewController {

}
```